# Clicking through a transparent .png

Tags: html, css, png, transparent, myspace

First off, I would like to say that myspace is a pain. But, musicians love it, and I can make some money doing layouts for them. I overlayed a layer of .png's over myspace's original look, but need to utilize the myspace music player. So, I made a picture frame that surrounds the myspace player that has a transparent center so you can see the myspace player. unfortunately, the player doesn't have full functionality. It seems to respond correctly when I hover, but not when I click. does anyone know how to solve this problem?

You can see what I'm talking about here: myspace.com/gprettydesigns

Comment: Sadly the PNG is in a layer that's sitting right on top of your Flash piece and you cannot click through it.[1] A possible solution is, or to slice up the image so it doesn't cover the flash element, or try getting the flash object on top of the image (z-index comes to mind.) [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001551/overlaying-a-transparent-png-over-a-swf-disables-all-click-events-in-the-swf

Answer (score 92):

add

```
pointer-events: none;
```

on your overlay to alow click events to pass through it. It's a fairly recent property so not all browser may understand it.

More informations on pointer-events on  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/pointer-events

Comment: Working on IE11

Answer (score 3):

The best way would generally be to slice the image up into pieces and place them so that nothing overlays the music player.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use z-index to position the image underneath the player, more on this here: http://www.echoecho.com/csslayers.htm

Answer (score 0):

Put the background image on a div then use z-index to position it behind the player. The advantage of putting a background image on a div and using z-index is that it'll be faster than using an actual inline image.

Answer (score -1):

Clap clap clap to you! I've done sone MySpace tweaking and know it's a real PITA.

Change the CSS here:

```
#shell {
    visibility:hidden;
    z-index:200;
}
```

I don't remember if this is feasible or if they only accept inline CSS.

Not really question related but now you can also have bandpages on facebook via [RootMusic](http://www.rootmusic.com/). MySpace will probably be overrun in no time so I would also give them a look.

Good luck dealing with the spaghetti tables of MySpace.