# Transparent PNG obscuring a link

Tags: html, png

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clicking through a transparent .png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080746/clicking-through-a-transparent-png)
>   [Click through a DIV to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)

I have a PNG image on my page (positioned absolutely to a place where it fits with the rest of background), and the problem is that a hyperlink in another DIV element is 'obscured' by the transparent part of the image. The result is that the hyperlink is clearly visible and readable, but I cannot click on it.

Is there a way around it?

EDIT: I was surprised that this question wasn't asked before, but obviously, I didn't look hard enough:

[Clicking through a transparent .png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080746/clicking-through-a-transparent-png?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Click through a DIV to underlying elements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3680429/1456376)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the link a higher z-index than the image has.

Comment: see my comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Give the elements that are supposed to be "above" the image a z-index that is higher then the image

Comment: No, the transparent image is supposed to be *above* the text div (otherwise there would be little point in it being transparent, would it?). My problem is that the part of it that is transparent still prevents mouse events from getting through.