# Click through PNG image - only if clicked coordinate is transparent

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an image like this:

[image]

I want it so that when I click the transparent parts, the click should go through to the underlying element, but when I click a non-transparent part, this image element should get the click.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clicking through a transparent .png](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080746/clicking-through-a-transparent-png)

Comment: use map or svg  :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Use a temporary **canvas** element.
2. Get the overlay image **mousedown
   coordinates**.
3. Populate your canvas with that **image data**.
4. Read from canvas the 1px image data (from the same coordinates).
   If the retrieved **Alpha channel data is `0`** means it's
   **transparent**.
5. If pixel is transparent set **pointerEvents** to `"none"` and **retrieve the  underneath element** using [Document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint)
   1 Trigger `"click"` event on the underneath element
6. Reset **pointerEvents** back to `"auto"` for all overlays

```js
var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");

$('#logo').on("mousedown", function(event) {
  
  // Get click coordinates
  var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
      y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop,
      w = ctx.canvas.width = this.width,
      h = ctx.canvas.height = this.height,
      alpha;

  // Draw image to canvas
  // and read Alpha channel value
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, w, h);
  alpha = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data[3]; // [0]R [1]G [2]B [3]A

  // If pixel is transparent,
  // retrieve the element underneath and trigger it's click event
  if( alpha===0 ) {
    this.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    $(document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY)).trigger("click");
    this.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
  } else {
    console.log("LOGO clicked!");
  }
});


$("#green").on("click", function(){
  console.log("Green image clicked!");
});
```

```css
img{border:1px solid #000;}
img + img{position:absolute;top:0; left:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="green" src="//placehold.it/200x140/cf5">
<img id="logo"  src="data:image/png;base64,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
">
```

Comment: Wow, this is great. I wish I could accept the other answer also, but this is more elegant and easy to use. Thanks.

Comment: In the case of a transparent pixel, where does the click event propagate to? I'm trying to catch it from an underlying image but it doesn't fire.

Comment: If your parent element has a click listener than clicking on the transparent part will propagate. Else... the click will be stopped from propagation.

Comment: I see, so in my case it goes to the parent div. How can I capture that click on an underlying image instead of the parent div?

Comment: Get the ElementFromPoint

Comment: im on mobile currently. Will expand my answer in 30min or so.

Comment: Then perhaps I'm missing something. Because the on() handler is assigned to all images of the same class in this div, but the transparent click directly goes to the div, not the underlying image.

Comment: @Nick As I've said, use `elementFromPoint`. The trick was to quickly hide the logo, get the element from point (the element underneath), trigger it's click event, and than finally show the logo. The hide/show is not visible to the eye, but allows to get the right element from coordinates: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint. Anyways, updated my answer if this comment seems a bit fuzzy :)

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

For your scenario, would it be sufficient to capture click events on the non-transparent area of the image?

This can be done using a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) and some JavaScript:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ab6aW.jpg" alt="" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
<area
  href="javascript:alert('You clicked on the image!')"
  shape="poly" 
  coords="193,148,50,193,254,292,461,191,302,141,332,99,285,27,220,16,170,89"
/>
</map>
```

(The coordinates were derived using [this site](http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/).)

Comment: Yes, this will do. Would this be the preferred way to do it, or would it be easier to get the alpha value of the clicked pixel and check for transparency? Because with this I need to generate maps for each image.

Comment: If you can figure out how to get the alpha value of the clicked pixel, go for it! Otherwise, it may take less time to just manually create `map`s for each image (depending on the number of images, and the complexity of their transparencies). It only took me a few seconds to create the map in my answer, but it is pretty rough around the edges.

Comment: Tracing the image non transparent area is a hell of a job.