# Click only not transparent Part of svg img

Tags: reactjs, image, svg, canvas, onclick

I'm currently building a website with help of React and docusaurus, and there I want to have a svg image (located in static/astronaut-light.svg) that switches color as soon as I poke it.
The problem is that the onClick/onMouseEnter event gets triggered on the transparent parts too,
which isn't a preferred behavior. (See video) 
-> It should only switch its color if I click happens on a non transparent part.

Youtube Video: https://youtu.be/tZ2UfWE1Aw4 
Website: https://agile-ts.org/ 
SourceCode: https://github.com/agile-ts/documentation/blob/develop/src/_pages/LandingPage/components/HeaderView/components/Astronaut/index.tsx

I tried to solve this problem by checking if the pixel is transparent or not..
but I couldn't get it to work. (See code below)

```
  const imageRef = useRef<HTMLImageElement>(null);
  const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');

  // https://medium.com/@pdx.lucasm/canvas-with-react-js-32e133c05258
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487569/click-through-png-image-only-if-clicked-coordinate-is-transparent
  const trigger = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLImageElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    // Get click coordinates
    const x = event.pageX - imageRef.current.offsetLeft;
    const y = event.pageY - imageRef.current.offsetTop;
    const w = (ctx.canvas.width = imageRef.current.width);
    const h = (ctx.canvas.height = imageRef.current.height);

    // Draw image to canvas
    // and read Alpha channel value
    ctx.drawImage(imageRef.current, 0, 0, w, h);
    const alpha = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data[3]; // [0]R [1]G [2]B [3]A

    // If pixel is transparent,
    // retrieve the element underneath and trigger it's click event
    if (alpha === 0) {
      console.log('alpha0');
      imageRef.current.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
      const element = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
      // element.trigger('click');
      imageRef.current.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    } else {
      setIsRaised(true);
      console.log('LOGO clicked!');
    }

  return (
    <div className={clsx(styles.Container, className)}>
      <animated.img
        ref={imageRef}
        onMouseEnter={trigger}
        style={animated_Astronaut}
        className={styles.Image}
        src={`img/astronaut-${dark ? 'dark' : 'light'}.svg`}
        alt={'Astronaut'}
      />
      <div className={styles.Text}>Poke me  to mutate my color State.</div>
    </div>
  );
```

Maybe you have an idea how to solve this problem. 
Thank you :D

Comment: Looks like you're including the SVG via an img element. You'd need to use an object or iframe element instead or have the SVG inline on the page itself.

Comment: yeah sure.. I've already tried to use 'object' and 'iframe' but both ended up in the same behavior.. and an inline svg works.. but is for me no clean option..

Comment: To the Browser the SVG becomes a **square** IMG. So one (complex) workaround is to get the ``clientX,Y`` coordinates of the click, determine the IMG relative position, extract the SVG, create the SVG as (hidden) DOM element, calculate the "clicked" location. Use ``elementsFromPoint`` to determine the clicked SVG element... and you are using React.. so you probably need to do more to make it all work in the DOM.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman yeah as you can see in the code snippet above I tried to solve the problem in a similar way.. but I couldn't manage to get it to work..

Comment: I don't use React because I prefer real DOM over virtualDOM. I would check if your ``canvas`` method actually works in a non-React JSFiddle/CodePen

Comment: An inline SVG **IS** the clean way.  Any other approach would be a hack.  If you don't want the SVG in your static HTML, then you can always fetch and insert it into the page at run time.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau yeah I ended up with an inline svg.. with not clean I meant to paste the svg directly into the code.. I outsourced it into a separate component.. 
may I ask you how to fetch and insert a svg at runtime.. thank you ;D

Comment: @BennoDev Since you are using React, then making it a component, as you have already done, is a good solution.